# iPod touch 6g 9.3.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: music, rhythmbox, banshee, ipod

A friend of mine bought an iPod Touch 6G (now with upgraded iOS 9.3.4), thinking it would work with his 6-year old Macbook running Mac OS X 10.6.8. Since they're both Apple products, compatibility matters didn't even cross his mind.
With iOS 9.3.4, you need iTunes 12, but you can't run iTunes 12 on a Mac OS X 10.6.8 machine unless you upgrade to 10.11 El Capitan, BUT the hardware is too old for the upgrade. Talk about planned obsolescence... So I figured a change of OS might be (at least part of) the solution.
I tried many lightweight Linux distros, installed `libimobiledevice`, `gtkpod`, Rhythmbox, Banshee, etc. All I could get done was mounting the iPod with access to the DCIM folder.

Long story short, **I'm looking for any way to manage an iPod Touch 6G running iOS 9.3.4 on any Linux machine**. I don't care if I have to jailbreak the iPod and/or wipe everything, I just need an OS that handles file transfer to and from an iPod.
My fear is that my only option is to install Windows XP in a virtual machine for the single purpose of running iTunes...

I bet I'm not the only one looking for a solution to work with iPod 6G on a Linux machine, so any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Good luck jailbreaking iOS 9.3.

Comment: This may help: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/transfer-music-media-ipod-ios-device-linux/

Comment: Or this: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/can-get-ios-7-device-work-well-linux/

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6867610?start=0&tstart=0